# Azure Error 404 - Web app not found

Tags: asp.net, http, azure, asp.net-core

I have publish my asp.net core web app on azure and assigned custom domain to my web app such as www.example.com and example.com. I have changed the CNAME, A and TXT record and added my hostname without issue. However, the non-www, example.com, sometimes work and sometimes it doesn't and i get an Error 404 - Web App not found. The www.example.com is always working and i don't have any issue. I tried on multiple device and computers, different web browsers and sometime everything is fine for the non-www rule but sometime i get that 404 Error. What could possibly be the issue?

These are the records i added:

A Record:

www, @ and *

Txt Record:

www, @ and *

CNAME Record:

www, *

Answer (score 1):

On your DNS registrar, in addition to 'www' A record, you have to create a host A record with key '@' (meaning everything else) pointing to your azure external IP address. Thus example.com must work properly.

Comment: I added these:

A Record: @ IP, www IP, * IP
Txt Record: @ webappname, www webappname, * webappname
CNAME:  www webappname, * webappname

Comment: Are you using cloudflare ? or something alike ?

Comment: No i don't use cloudflare.. It was working 20min ago now it is not working anymore

Comment: please try to create 'webappname.com' host A record. so you have only 'www' and 'webappname.com' A records. Delete other host A records.